# Reset input by typing a key. Jquery

Tags: jquery, reset

If I type a letter "a" I want to reset the input, however the first letter always remains in there. Anybody know how clean the input totally?

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hvx6y/)

Answer (score 4):

You can use `.preventDefault()` to stop the default behavior of the event, in this case prevent the a from being entered into the input. Like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#test').on('keypress', function(e){            
        if(e.which == 97) {
         e.preventDefault();            
         this.value = "";
        }           
    })
})​;
```

Updated your fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/hvx6y/1/

Comment: Yeah! It is true, I was a little blocked and didn´t see the simple solution. Thank you Christofer.

Answer (score 0):

Use `setTimeout` (with an argument of 1 or 0) to execute a tiny bit of code that clears the input.  This works because the code in setTimeout will execute AFTER the current keypress has been handled.

You can also prevent the current event from finishing its processing as Christofer Eliasson pointed out.